# Get colour of a pixel from an image file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, image, pixel

I'm trying to get the colour of a pixel from an image file using PowerShell. The code I have tried just returns the same values every single time even for different pixels which are different colours. This doesn't seem to be working correctly. I've tired saving the image file as bitmap or png or jpg. I would prefer it worked with a png if thats possible somehow.

```
$filename = "T1.bmp"
$image = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap $filename
$pixelColor = $null
$pixelColor = $image.GetPixel($104, $919)
$pixelColor

$image = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap $filename
$pixelColor = $null
$pixelColor = $image.GetPixel($1191, $300)
$pixelColor
```

Comment: `$image.GetPixel($104, $919)`  you are passing variables to this function. Do they have any values assigned to them? If you just want to pass the integer value remove the '$' `$image.GetPixel(104, 919)`. Otherwise it's returning the same value because it might just be grabbing the value from 0,0.

Comment: @kconsiglio thank you, that was a silly mistake. put your comment as the answer so i can accept it.

Comment: you're welcome! Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you were passing in variables to the function

```
$pixelColor = $image.GetPixel($104, $919)
$pixelColor = $image.GetPixel($1191, $300)
```

Unless you had values assigned to `$104, $919` or `$1191, $300` it most likely is just grabbing the pixel from 0,0 and is the same.
Changing to:

```
$pixelColor = $image.GetPixel(104, 919)
$pixelColor = $image.GetPixel(1191, 300)
```

Should fix the issue.